# Tkinter and text editor window - re write data shown

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I have a function that I'd like to re write the data into a text window using tkinter.
It works right now, although it re writes everything on one line. The function was taken from another script. How can I keep the lines it was reading + cleaning?

The input lines looks similar to this:

- ABC/DEF/5GH///IJK//23///694

and my output should look like:

- ABC, DEF, 5GH, IJK, (cleaned whitespace + numerics)

  ```
   def split_lines(fp, delimiter, remove='^[0-9.]+$'):
   with open(fp, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
       clean_list = []
       for line in file:
           tokens = line.split(delimiter)
           tokens = [re.sub(remove, "", token) for token in tokens]
           clean_list.extend(list(filter(lambda e: e.strip(), tokens)))
       txt_edit.delete("1.0", tk.END)
       text = clean_list
       txt_edit.insert(tk.END, text)
  ```

Comment: It would help if you could give half a dozen lines of input and how you expect that to appear after having been modified by your code.

Comment: Edited. @Bryan Oakley

Comment: What is *(cleaned whitespace + numerics)* actually based on the provided sample line?

Comment: @acw1668 I mean the output should delimit by the `"/", split by the whitespaces and remove (replace by whitespace) numeric only elements.

Answer (score 2):

You need to join the list elements with newlines if you want each element in the list to be on a separate line.

```
text = "\n".join(clean_list)
```

Comment: thank you! This helps me understand more. However now it prints each individual element on a new line, where I'm needing to print the new lines that were cleaned from the original text file. The idea is to take sample data like `ABC/DEF/GHI/` and clean it, then re print those clean lines individually in the window.

Comment: @Chaotic.Python: if that's the case, then you need to first make sure that your `clean_list` is set up so that each list element is a whole line.

Comment: I understand, apologies as I am new to Python. How would I facilitate something like that?